# convert mysql date format from ISO to UK using PHP

Tags: mysql, date, format

I have a date field in a mysql database which I am trying to display in a .php document. it currently displays in yyyy-mm-dd when I insert the following code:

```
<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['dateend']; ?>
```

However I would like it to display in dd-mm-yyyy

I need the simplest/cleanest solution.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($row_rs_dealItem['dateend']);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
?>
```